# finding 16 largest values in R Vector

Tags: r, vector

Given **the R code below**, I was wondering **how to create two columns such that the 16 largest values of LR and their corresponding xs when "x" is bounded between .4 and .8** be shown? (**a column for x** & **a column for the corresponding LR**)?

```
n=100
h=60
x=seq(0,1,by=0.02)
LR <- dbeta(x,h+1,n-h+1)/max(dbeta(x,h+1,n-h+1))
```

I'm trying the following, but can't create the two columns:

```
head(sort(LR[which(x<=.8 & x>=.4)], decreasing=TRUE), 16)
```

Comment: Did you just forget the `sort()`? `head(sort(LR[which(x<=.8 & x>=.4)], decreasing=TRUE), 16)` What is the desired output here?

Comment: Please let me modify my question.

Comment: You could either use `order` or "index.return = TRUE" in `sort` and subset "LR" and "x" appropriately

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: @user138773 : `order` instead of `sort` returns the indices of the sorted values instead of the sorted values temselves: `i = x <= 0.8 & x >= 0.4; LRi = LR[i]; xi = x[i]; o = head(order(LRi, decreasing = TRUE), 16); cbind(LRi[o], xi[o])`

Comment: Very elegant, thank you very very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x, LR)
df1 <- df %>%
  filter((x >= 0.4) & (x <= 0.8)) %>% 
  top_n(16, LR)

# to save the data
write.csv(df1, "abc.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: Can the downvote explain the reason? I will be glad to modify the answer if I misunderstand anything. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, but how can I export the output of the dplyr as a table?

Comment: If you want to output as a csv/txt file, you can use `write.csv`/`write.table` to do that.

Comment: so, should I create a name for any part of the dplyr code? Could you please write the short code that shows what you exactly mean?

Comment: Thanks very much, I already have upvoted your answer, but still can't understand who downvoted it.

Comment: While it works,  I don't think the combination of `arrange` and `head` is the optimal way of producing a subset, and is kind of "off-label" for `head`. Instead I believe using `top_n(16,LR)` or a combination of `min_rank` and `slice` would be better.

Comment: Yes, `top_n(16,LR)` will be a better answer. Thanks, Jake.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `sort` to sort the subset of the vector `LR` under your condition:

```
sort(LR[x <= .8 & x >= .4],decreasing = TRUE)[1:16]
```

Comment: If the data set is large you can also save time by adding `partial = 1:16`.

Comment: Of course, I always forget about partial. Thanks @Barker